# how to get a single value of a policy on a remote computer via POWERSHELL

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am in need to create a CSV file of a list of servers (WinServer 2008/2012).  The list will show all of the server names and the current value of a given RSOP policy.  THere are over 400 servers.

My intent is to create a Powershell script to scan the servers and report the values.  Most of the guidance I receive returns a complete HTML or XML response.  For example:

```
get-gpresultantsetofpolicy -reporttype xml -path c:\reports\LocalUserAndComputerReport.xml
```

Is there a way to just get the value of the policy I want so I can scan 400 servers and get the list I need?

Thanks.

Comment: ServerFault is NOT a free script writing service.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, RSOP reports are all or nothing. You can't generate a individual results for specific settings.

However with the resulting XML file and Powershell's native XML support, it shouldn't be too hard to consume the resulting XML, and pull out the data for the specific setting (or settings) you care about.